# addView order not working

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

I am adding a `cameraView`, a `glSurfaceView`, and an `ImageView` to a `relativeLayout` in that order, but the result has them ordered from top bottom to top (`cameraView`, `imageView`, `glSurfaceView`) any specific reason? is it because the `glSurfaceView` redraws it's self internally?

code snippit for the adding:

rel.addView(glView);

```
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM,1);
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
        params.rightMargin = 20;
        // add Camera to view 
        rel.addView(camPreview, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
        rel.addView(glView);
        rel.addView(imageView,params);
```

question really is.. how can i assure the imageView is always on top

I thought that the `GLSurfaceView's` `onDrawFrame` method was bringing the `GlSurfaceView` to the top of the view list, so i added a call back to a public method on the mainActivity from the onDrawFrame Method that looks like this:

```
public void ajustOverlay(){
        imageView.bringToFront();
        Log.v("parent: ", "ajust overlay");
    }
```

That still doesn't seem to keep the `imageView` on top

Comment: Maybe you can use the view hierarchy tool?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok after trying the solutions above and various other solutions, and banging my head against concrete for almost a year now, i ifnally have it working..  the key was to  ad the following line before adding the glView

```
glView.setZOrderMediaOverlay(true);
rel.addView(camPreview, camParams);
rel.addView(glView, glParams);
rel.addView(imageView, imageParams);
```

Answer (score 2):

You're adding your views without enough rules for a RelativeLayout, that's maybe the reason why the result is not what you expect. 
For example the `RelativeLayout.BELOW` rule have to be defined to be sure that a view is below another one.

First, you should try to build your layout in XML so you will be able to look at the result on Eclipse.
And then apply programmatically all the rules that are inside your file or building your XML hierarchy easily thanks to a `LayoutInflater`.
I really advise you the [`LayoutInflater`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html) solution if you can, for many reasons (maintenance, reformating, multiscreen handling, ...).

You should also read the complete documentation about RelativeLayout to format it correctly : [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html)

Comment: RelativeLayout.BELOW aligns one views, bottom to the top of another correct? thats not what i am trying to do, i am trying to overlay one view over another

Comment: Ok so the `RelativeLayout` should be ok for your case. Did or can you use the `LayoutInflater` to instanciate your view?

Comment: I did not use layoutInflater, as there is no existing xml layout.

Comment: i did this:  RelativeLayout rel = new RelativeLayout(this);
         // set as main view
         setContentView(rel);

Comment: Im thinking the problem is that the GLSurfaceView has an onDrawMethod and that somehow always brings it to the front.. is there a way to make sure it stays below the imageview

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same ordering problem trying to place three regular `LinearLayout` objects side by side in a parent `RelativeLayout`.  To correct the problem, you simply need to add one more parameter when you call the `addView` method.  It is the second parameter of three and it represents the index of the order you want the views to be added.

So this should work for you:

```
rel.addView(camPreview, 0, camParams);
rel.addView(glView, 1, glParams);
rel.addView(imageView,2, imageParams);
```